# Order of rendered list items differs from items order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, aura, array

I have a following Aura code sample:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();

    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var arr = [].concat(component.get("v.arr"));

        arr.push(response.getReturnValue());

        component.set("v.arr", arr);
    }
});
```

Which is being rendered via `aura:iteration` as follows:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.arr}" var="item">
  <c:customComp
    record="{!item}"
  />
</aura:iteration>
```

The problem is, that order of rendered `c:customComp` on view differs from actual order of items in `v.arr`.

How can it be? Maybe anyone can explain and give an advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you console.log to check the order in init when it gets loaded? Is that differerent from the one that gets constructed in apex?

Comment: @RedDevil, yes, I did. It's the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug as reported in salesforce [issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ep3yQAA):

Workaround:

Set an empty array before setting the actual array of items. Note: This 
   workaround will rerender the whole array.

```
Code: 
cmp.set("v.someListAttribute", [].concat(updatedArray)); 
or 
cmp.set("v.someListAttribute", []); 
cmp.set("v.someListAttribute", [].concat(updatedArray));
```